# Codeigniter php check/uncheck all checkboxes without using jquery or javascript

Tags: php, codeigniter

Is it possible to check/uncheck all checkboxes at once without using jquery or javascript (only php and codeigniter)?

Comment: Yes, it is. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try a $_GET?

```
<?php

$all_checked = false;

if (!empty($_GET['all_checked']))
    $all_checked = true;

for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++)
    if ($all_checked)
        echo '<input type="checkbox" checked="checked">';
    else
        echo '<input type="checkbox">';
?>
<a href="?all_checked=1">Check All</a>
<a href="?all_checked=0">Uncheck All</a>
```

Now when you click on the link, it either checks all or unchecks all.

[Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hb9-qyv) (Press F9 or Run)